# error: sorry, too many clients already when transferring Node project from Windows to Debian

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have a Node.js project using the pg library. I am using a client pool to handle database connections. On Windows 10, I have no issues and the project works fine.

When attempting to run this project on a Debian system, I get the following error:

```
error: sorry, too many clients already
```

The max_connections on both systems are the same, 100.

I would like to avoid just increasing the max_connections of the PostgreSQL database as this doesn't actually resolve my issue, instead delaying it until I have more data in the database.

Does anyone know what could be causing this? Below is my pg configuration:

```
const pool = new Pool({
    user: 'my_user',
    host: 'localhost',
    database: 'my_database',
    password: 'my_password',
    port: 5432,
    connectionTimeoutMillis: 2000,
    idleTimeoutMillis: 500,
    max: 40 //Max number of clients that the pool should contain
});
```

Edit: I have just noticed that I am using PostgreSQL 11 on Debian and 12 on Windows, could this have something to do with it?

Comment: It usually means multiple pools are initialising. How are you calling this code? Maybe the new postgres install has a low `max_connections` setting.

Comment: The max_connections is set at 100. Do you know how I'd check if multiple pools are being initialised?

Comment: Check in pg_stat_activity to see where these connections are coming from, or turn on log_connections to the same info without having to capture it in real time.

Comment: Thanks, this has solved my issue. Turns out I was creating a new pool for each connection - I'd set up a module incorrectly.